# Книги по паттернам

Tags: книги

Посоветуйте хорошие книги по паттернам, желательно болле обобщенные. 
Спасибо

Comment: А стандартный труд GoF [пойдёт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)?

Comment: В дополнение к комментарию @VladD, посоветую еще *Паттерны проектирования* из серии _Head First_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Есть еще хорошая книга Р. С. Мартина и М. Мартина 
> «Принципы, паттерны и методики гибкой разработки на языке C#».

Прекрасная книга. В ней описываются SOLID - основные принципы объектно-ориентированного проектирования, которые лежат во основе многих паттернов (еще есть более старое издание Р.Мартин, "Быстрая разработка программного обеспечения", то же самое, но с примерами на языке Java).

Еще книги по проектированию и паттернам:

1. Руководство Microsoft по проектированию архитектуры приложений.
2. Гамма и др. "Приёмы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования".
3. Гранд М. Шаблоны проектирования в Java
4. Влиссидес Д. - Применение шаблонов проектирования. Дополн. штрихи

Здесь можно найти описание паттернов тестирования (в контексте TDD):

1. Кент Бек, "Экстремальное программирование. Разработка через тестирование".
2. Грэхем Ли, Разработка через тестирование для iOS

Здесь можно почитать про паттерны, наиболее часто используемые в проектировании интерпрайз приложений:

1. Мартин Фаулер, Архитектура корпоративных программных приложений (книга содержит описание паттернов, которые можно применять при проектировании back-end'а в вебапликациях)
2. Хоп, Шаблоны интеграции корпоративных приложений

Answer (score 4):

Есть еще хорошая книга Р. С. Мартина и М. Мартина «Принципы, паттерны и методики гибкой разработки на языке C#».

Answer (score 2):

В книге Мэтт Зандстра - "PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования" ( 2011 ) рассматриваются шаблоны проектирования применительно к PHP.

Answer (score 1):

на [хабре полно статей](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD+%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0&target_type=posts), в которых описываются паттерны и книги по ним

Answer (score 0):

По JavaScript есть [перевод на русский книги Addy Osmani «Паттерны для масштабируемых JavaScript-приложений»](http://largescalejs.ru/). В книге речь идет о создании архитектуры приложений на базе паттернов «Медиатор», «Модуль» и «Фасад».