# Подскажите хорошие книги по изучению архитектуры приложений (в частности Android с подходом Clean Architecture), архитектурных паттернов

Tags: android, шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура, mvp, solid

Подскажите хорошие книги, которые помогут строить правильную архитектуру приложений, в частности интересует разработка под Android с подходом Clean Architecture, чтобы объяснялись паттерны MVP, MVVP, MVC, VIPER, чтобы освещались такие темы, как интеракторы, презентеры, для чего они нужны, чтобы были примеры их использования и так далее. Очень интересует данная тема, в голове есть какие-то куски разрозненной информации по этим вопросам, но хотелось бы разложить все по полочкам и иметь полную картину

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-android

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-android)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/345252/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/297672/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc/304181#304181

Comment: https://github.com/AndroidArchitecture/AndroidArchitectureBook

Comment: По чистой архитектуре (в общем) есть одноименная книжка у Uncle Bob. Касательно Android сложнее. Могу посоветовать только статьи. Русскоязычные есть на хабре, англоязычные -- на медиуме (гуглится легко). Как пример, могу посоветовать: [раз](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture), [два](https://github.com/Gaket/Earthquakes) и [три](https://gitlab.com/terrakok/gitlab-client) (Kotlin). Также, в Telegram есть архитектурный чат по Android.